# Scheduling of Automation Tasks Using Jenkins With Selenium Java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cloudbees

I was wondering if I could get some advice regarding automating the scheduling of selenium test cases in java. I have a set of test cases written in Java with selenium and maven that go onto a website, clicks a few buttons which in turn downloads a daily file.

I use AutoItX do interact with the download window to choose my save location and type a name etc.

The code works perfectly for when I execute it normally in Intellij. However I now need to find a process that can kick the build of the code off automatically.

I thought about using Jenkins however it is unable to access my download folder/file system when it comes to downloading files. I also thought about setting a task scheduler on my system to run a batch file that would kick off the project but I cannot guarantee the system will always be on and logged in.

The question I have is: Is there a way to grant jenkins a way to interact with my file system or is there an alternative tool which will allow me to do this.
Or am I missing a config step that will allow me to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jenkins as a windows service you can allow it to interact with desktop and run it as a user with elevated privileges. e.g.

[image]

Comment: hi Glib - Thanks for the response - if I do it this way will the Jenkins essentially mock log in as an administrator and be able to interact with the desktop? So essentially what is the functionality of Jenkins when it this permission

Comment: Hi Mark, the key is that all child processes started by Jenkins will be able to interact with desktop which is what you want in selenium tests. More on interaction with desktop can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule Jenkins job that will be triggered at certain intervals. e.g. you may want to run it at 9PM then Build periodically is the option you may want to use.